# Using jdbcTemplate nested in another jdbcTemplate (Before start of result set)

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I make a query:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQueryForGetNodes,  new Object[]{treeId, versionId}, rs -> {
    NodeType nodeType = NodeType.get(rs.getInt("NodeTypeId"));
    int nodeId = rs.getInt("NodeId");
    SmbpTreeSwitchCase switchCase = new SmbpTreeSwitchCase();
    switchCase.setSwitchConditionType(getSwitchTypeByNodeId(nodeId));
    smbpTreeNodes.add(switchCase);
}); 

private SwitchConditionType getSwitchTypeByNodeId(int nodeId) {
        String sqlQueryForGetSwitchTypeByNodeId = "SELECT SwitchConditionTypeId FROM RE.SwitchCondition sc WHERE sc.NodeId = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQueryForGetSwitchTypeByNodeId, resultSet -> {
            return SwitchConditionType.get(resultSet.getInt("SwitchConditionTypeId"));
        }, nodeId);
 }
```

And in this query, I need to subquery another table in method `getSwitchTypeByNodeId` to fill the object with data.

But I'm getting an error:

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT SwitchConditionTypeId FROM RE.SwitchCondition sc WHERE sc.NodeId = ?]; Before start of result set; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
```

What am I doing wrong? Tell me how to correctly make a subquery in `jdbcTemplate`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your two lambdas in your two calls to `JdbcTemplate.query` have different types and hence are being treated differently by Spring.

The first call, which appears to work, appears to use [the overload of the `JdbcTemplate.query` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-) that takes a `String`, an `Object[]` and a `RowCallbackHandler` and returns `void`.  In this case, your lambda is a `RowCallbackHandler` which is called once for each row in the result-set.  Spring will be advancing the result-set from one row to the next; it's just up to you to do something with each row.

The second call, however, appears to use [the overload of `JdbcTemplate.query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-) that takes a `String`, a `ResultSetExtractor` and a varargs array of arguments, and returns whatever the `ResultSetExtractor` returns.  When using a `ResultSetExtractor`, Spring will call you only once and expect you to do all of the handling of the result-set.  In particular, you will need to check whether the result-set contains any data at all.

Try modifying your second lambda to something like the following:

```
       return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQueryForGetSwitchTypeByNodeId, resultSet -> {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                return SwitchConditionType.get(resultSet.getInt("SwitchConditionTypeId"));
            } else {
                // SQL query returned no rows.  TODO handle this somehow...
            }
        });
```